# Stop auto triggering circle ci pipeline

Tags: cypress, circleci

I have configured my cypress test suite to circleci pipeline. The issue I am facing is that when I pushed my git branch or accept a pull request for the branch connected to the circle ci pipeline, it starts to run the test. I just don't need that I'm preferred to run the pipeline manually from the circle ci dashboard. Can someone guide me to fix the issue please? Attached my circleci yaml file below..

```
    version: 2
jobs:
- request-testing:
          type: approval
  build:
  
    docker:
      - image: cypress/base:14.16.0
        environment:
          ## this enables colors in the output
          TERM: xterm
    working_directory: ~/app
    parallelism: 4
    resource_class: large
    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}
            - v1-deps
      - run:
          name: Install Dependencies
          command: npm ci
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-deps-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          # cache NPM modules and the folder with the Cypress binary
          paths:
            - ~/.npm
            - ~/.cache
       #run: $(npm bin)/cypress run
      - run: $(npm bin)/cypress run --parallel --record --key 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way would be to edit the CircleCI webhook in your VCS repository settings, and unselect both the "Pushes" and "Pull requests" events.
This way there won't be any webhook delivery sent to CircleCI for these types of events, and therefore no build will be triggered.